# How to determine if last N rows in a dynamic range contain 0?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which contains a list that adds a new row daily. I would like to create a formula which determines if the data for the previous 365 days is equal to 0. The difficulty is referencing a range of data that continually changes.

[image: Sample of spreadsheet included]

I have tried to create a range from the last used cell in the column and subtract 365 cells. (Last used cell:Last used cell - 365)

If the last 365 days of data equals zero every day, I would like to display the text "Discontinue", if not equal to zero display "No action".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to locate the last row with data.

```
=IF(SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1e99,B:B)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1e99,B:B)-365))=0,"Discontinued","No Action")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

u can try something like this.

on the row 366, and assuming that u are testing row D, u put

```
=if(sum(D366:D1)=0;"Discontinued"; "No action")
```

it sums the previous 365 rows and if its 0 shows "Discontinued", else "No Action".

For the first 365 rows, i dont know what u want to do.

good luck